# Black screen after installation of Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, system-installation, asus

I did a fresh complete install of Ubuntu 18.04 on my ASUS M32CD desktop.

Everything during install went fine. At the end it said it was complete complete, and would reboot. Popped the disc out. Rebooted itself back into bios so I changed it back from CD boot as primary to HD.

When it booted up for Ubuntu screen and then everything went black and can’t do anything now! Ugh. Help

Comment: Now it seems my freaking $1000 PC is borked. Tried reinstalling that froze up. Now what?!?

Comment: It has a Nvidia graphics. Use `nomodeset` to boot the live session, install and until the proprietary Nvidia graphics drivers are installed.

Comment: I had the same problem I found a workaround here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1144800/ubuntu-18-04-2-boot-stuck-on-purple-screen-after-updates

Answer (score 11):

#### Enable nomodeset from GRUB boot menu

nomodeset is a kernel boot option. Adding the `nomodeset` parameter instructs the kernel to not load video drivers and use BIOS modes instead until X is loaded.

**Safe Graphics Mode**. A new option is added to the GRUB menu in 19.04 and later which will boot with nomodeset on. This may help you resolve issues on certain graphics cards and allow you to boot and install any proprietary drivers needed by your system.

Immediately after the motherboard / computer manufacturer logo splash screen appears when the computer is booting, with BIOS, quickly press and hold the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key, which will bring up a GNU GRUB menu screen. With UEFI press (perhaps several times) the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key to get to the GNU GRUB menu screen. Sometimes the manufacturer's splash screen is a part of the Windows bootloader, so when you power up the machine it goes straight to the GNU GRUB menu screen, and then pressing <kbd>Shift</kbd> is unnecessary.

You will see a GNU GRUB menu screen that looks like this:

[image]

Press <kbd>e</kbd> to enter editing mode. This will bring up a GNU GRUB screen that looks like this:

[image]

Use the arrow keys to navigate when screen editing the above screen. Navigate to after the string on this screen that starts with `root=`. In this example screen the full string is `root=` followed by `UUID=` and a hexadecimal string as shown below:

```
root=UUID=bcf15ef2-a0b2-4753-9558-8399dd12a729
```

Immediately after this string replace `ro quiet splash` by `nomodeset quiet splash`. This change is only temporary — it will just be used once and GRUB won't remember it in the future. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>F10</kbd> to boot with the `nomodeset` option that was added. If you make a mistake, press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to go back to the previous screen.

#### Install proprietary graphics driver

Ubuntu 18.04 is bundled with a tool named *ubuntu-drivers-common* which detects and installs additional driver packages. The proprietary graphics driver can be installed with the following commands:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install  
sudo reboot
```

The `sudo ubuntu-drivers install` command installs drivers that are appropriate for automatic installation including their dependencies, and the proprietary graphics driver will also be updated automatically when an update is available. If your computer has an Nvidia GPU `ubuntu-drivers install` will install the proprietary graphics driver for it, otherwise if your computer has an AMD GPU its graphics driver is included in the default Ubuntu installation.

When installing a proprietary graphics driver, it is not necessary to uninstall the open source graphics driver. The two graphics drivers can be installed alongside each other allowing the open source graphics driver to be used as a fallback alternative in case there is a problem using the proprietary graphics driver.

Comment: I don’t think it has Nvidia graphics card. It said it had intel chipset graphics card.

Comment: I tried this and nothing happens when pressing shift

Comment: I finally got it into GNU but nothing works my keyboard won’t go up or down or let me select anything ‍♂️

Comment: I've dealt with black screens before and the if you have a phone you're internet connected, and if the keyboard works you can use Ctrl+Alt+F3 to get into a virtual console and run `sudo` commands. The keyboard doesn't work in this situation. I keep a real lightweight Linux live USB on hand to test if I can use the mouse and keyboard in a live Linux session. If I can, that means my hardware is still good and I can at least boot or reinstall Windows.

Comment: Ok no idea what that means lol

Comment: This crap is way over my head. Think I’ll just reinstall windows 10 again 

Comment: I hope the Canonical team sees your comment, as this is exactly what is holding back Ubuntu from mainstream adoption