# Black screen after reinstalling Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, windows-10

I tried to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 in UEFI mode. An earlier non-accessible version of Ubuntu 16.04 (due to a grub issue) was installed in legacy mode over which I am trying to reinstall Ubuntu 16.04 using a live USB, but in UEFI mode now.

As soon as the reinstallation (in previously installed Ubuntu's partition only) was completed, after restarting Ubuntu 16.04 a black screen with the following message was displayed.

```
[    7.958699] Couldn't get size: 0x800000000000000e
[   10.239669] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[   10.239699] sd 2:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

How can I fix it and dual boot Ubuntu 16.04 successfully?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it) Basically you have Nvidia Graphics (I know from your other question) so you need `nomodeset` until the Nvidia drivers are installed. The error/warning messages have nothing to with the GUI not coming up.

Comment: It looks like that there's no caching mechanism for your hard drive. It's disabled or maybe not recognized for some reason, so the system will write directly to the drive.

Comment: Hi @GabrielaGarcia , i don't actually have Nvidia Graphics card in my machine so why would i need those drivers ? Umm do you have any other possible solution to my problem ?

Comment: @karel thanks for the edit of my question . And i don't think https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085807/black-screen-after-installation-of-ubuntu-18-04  is a possible duplicate for my black screen problem because there's a message as well on that black screen and also i don't have any Nvidia graphics card so i don't think it'd be any beneficial for me to set `nomodeset` . I'd be really glad if you can provide me any solutions specific to my problem , Thanks !

Comment: Aren't you using a Acer Travelmate P259 series?

Comment: Yes i am using Acer Travelmate P259 series , model no : N16Q2 . But it does not have a graphics card and it has i3 intel chip .

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Any possible solution ? i can't think of any solution that fixes my problem , Please help !

Comment: According to Toshiba yes, it does have a GeForce® 940MX graphics. It must have something because i3s do NOT have integrated graphics, so there. So, back to my first comment, the solution is using `nomodeset` until you install Nvidia graphics drivers. Nothing else to add.