# Blank screen after select ubuntu in install process

Tags: grub2

Please help, i had trouble with install process (ubuntu 16.04), after select install in boot menu, laptop doesn't response?

What should I do, please help?

My laptop Asus k42f, core i3 350M, 2,7 ghz, memory 3 GB, VGA Intel graphics Media Accelerator, resolution max 1366×768.

Comment: Please provide more information like your laptop make and model, processor type, GPU, etc. Thanks!

Comment: My laptop Asus k42f, core i3  350M, 2,7 ghz, memory 3 gb, VGA intel graphics Media Accelerator,  resolusi max 1366×768, is it get support from ubuntu?

Comment: Does this help? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085807/black-screen-after-installation-of-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: set gfxpayload=keep
 linux /casper/vmlinuz  file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper quiet splash ---
 initrd /casper/initrd    I already replace "quiet splash" with "nomodeset" but still not work, any other solition?? please help

Comment: Still not solve for me, is there any option?

Comment: Have you tried the brightness keys to see if the screen brightness is the problem. I have had this problem where the screen brightness was set to zero by default and increasing the brightness fixed the issue.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I already tried but still not solve for me also I have tried to replace "quiet splash" with "nomodeset" laptop still doen't give response, I did this method for 3 version ubuntu (14.04 LTS, 16.04 LTS and 18.04) for 32bit & 64bit,

Comment: Finally, I m success install ubuntu 16.04.6 after redownload ISO file an upgrade BIOS, thank for share knowlage

Comment: Awesome, you can answer your own question and then you can mark it as the accepted answer after a couple of days.