# Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key - Ryzen 5 & Nvidia

Tags: drivers, nvidia, 20.04, xorg

I am using a dual-boot Ubuntu 20.04 on a Lenovo Ideapad Gaming with Ryzen 5 and NVidia Geforce. First, I didn't manage to get Ubuntu installed. I tried to use the second answer in this thread [nouveau stalled at ffff error message while trying to convert Windows 10 laptop to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176048/nouveau-stalled-at-ffff-error-message-while-trying-to-convert-windows-10-laptop), which solved my issues.

If I use `mpirun`, this error pops up:

```
Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 key.
```

I tried to use `xhost +local:` but that did not work unfortunately. I also tried to switch the driver to X.org. If I do this and reboot, all options are grey and the only option available is a manually installed driver (which is then also selected).

Moreover, if I run the command `nvidia-settings`, I get the following errors:

```
(nvidia-settings:4351): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 15:16:53.124: g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed

ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file. This file should
       have been installed along with this driver at
       /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
       application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
       prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
       Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.

** Message: 15:16:53.170: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
** Message: 15:16:53.171: PRIME: is it supported? no
```

I think the magic cookie is perhaps due to mistakes in the drivers but I do not know how to proceed further. Any help is very much welcome.