# Ubuntu 18.04 installation failure because of drivers

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, 18.04

My laptop is LEGION R7000 2020, with R7-4800H and GTX1650 on it.

I'm totally new to Linux, and I'm trying to install Ubuntu 18.04 while keeping Win 10 on my laptop (dual boot).

I downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04.5 Desktop (64-bit) ISO and made a bootable USB Stick. I plan to install 18.04 on my SSD (SAMSUNG PM981a). Everything was smooth before rebooting.

After partitioning and installation, I rebooted, and came across [nouveau stalled at ffff error message while trying to convert Windows 10 laptop to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176048/nouveau-stalled-at-ffff-error-message-while-trying-to-convert-windows-10-laptop). After these `fffffff` errors, my laptop froze, like this:

[image: errors]

[image: errors]

[image: errors]

I checked a few posts:

- [nouveau stalled at ffff error message while trying to convert Windows 10 laptop to Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1176048/nouveau-stalled-at-ffff-error-message-while-trying-to-convert-windows-10-laptop),
- [Black screen after installation of Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085807/black-screen-after-installation-of-ubuntu-18-04)

and figured out it's a driver problem. So I tried all methods mentioned in these posts.

I got into GRUB menu to enable `nomodeset`. I successfully logged into Ubuntu. After this step, I tried the following:

1. Installed NVIDIA drivers (proprietary, tested 465 and proprietary 460) from Additional Drivers.
2. Ran the following commands in the terminal:

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall  
   sudo reboot
   ```

   both together and separately. But either way, my laptop freezes at reboot.

It'll get stuck at a black screen after reboot and the info shown on the black screen is:

```
Superblock last mount time is in the future
```

What should I do?

**EDIT 1**:

I have to stick to 18.04 because all the code that I'll be using are developed under 18.04. All my partners are using 18.04.

I've tried to install 20.04, the whole process was rather smooth and nothing went wrong. But still, I have to use 18.04.

Comment: As always, disable Secure Boot in UEFI. And why 18.04?

Comment: Try a newer release like Ubuntu 20.04, or even 21.04.  And check that your machine's firmware is up to date.

Comment: @ChanganAuto Secure Boot already disabled.

Comment: As above, the second comment.

Comment: @ChanganAuto But I got to use 18.04, I've edited and added my reason for doing so.

Comment: @ubfan1 is surely better qualified that I to explain why that reason is nonsense.

Comment: LTS releases have two stacks available; GA or HWE; the HWE when upgraded will use the 20.04 GA stack which was provided with the 18.04.5 media. Have you tried the GA stack?  (*drivers* are actually kernel modules; if using Ubuntu Server you can choose the stack you wish, but with Ubuntu Desktop the ISO used to install selects the installed stack, though it can be changed post-install).   I'd try the alternate stack, but you'll be using older kernel modules, for newer *drivers* you need newer software which won't exist on a 2018-April release of Ubuntu (other than the HWE stack)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should install Ubuntu 18.04 in the Virtualbox.

Because some of the drivers won't support Linux so  Virtualbox is the perfect solution.

You can try it.