# Issues installing Ubuntu (and Mint) - Black Screen on Live System & installed system - needs nomodeset

Tags: boot, dual-boot, nvidia

I've a pretty regular Ryzen Setup, but I can't install Ubuntu 18.04.4 (or others) with working graphics. I need nomodeset in the boot options so I have half-way support of anything graphical, but I would assume that my setup is supported by the defaults.

I get the GRUB and when I try to boot it instantly goes black, it does not show the splash.

My Setup:
Ryzen 2600X
MSI B450 Gaming Pro Carbon AC
ASUS GTX 2070 ROG
2 SSD

All Bios & similar should be up2date.

How to debug such an issue

Comment: Have you tried 18.04.4?   18.04.3 uses 19.04's software stack, where as 18.04.4 will use 19.10's so is later. We don't support Mint, but if the others include on-topic releases they may provide clues (other releases too but we need to know the age of software stacks, Ubuntu's *yy.mm* format makes that easy though there is the second HWE step with certain media for LTS releases)

Comment: Sorry, I've changed the question. Had 18.04 written before, thought "no, you used something fresh". I've installed 18.04.4. I've installed using nomodeset and I can boot using nomodeset, but now I'm pretty limited ;-) So how to proceed, even without `quiet` and `splash` I get a few brief lines of output and then it turns black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question with a solution:

- Boot Live System using nomodeset
- Install Ubuntu as usual
- Boot new installed Ubuntu using nomodeset
- Follow [Black screen after installation of Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085807/black-screen-after-installation-of-ubuntu-18-04)

  - short form: Run `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall; sudo reboot`
- reboot without nomodeset

Question remains: Why isn't the graphics card supported properly by the live system