# Ubuntu 18.04 shuts down automatically after boot

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, uefi, shutdown, startup

I am new to Ubuntu and linux in general. I have recently dual booted Ubuntu 18.04 along with Windows 10. I have installed it through UEFI. Whenever I boot into Ubuntu by choosing it from grub, it shows Ubuntu logo for sometime and then the system shuts down automatically. It happens every time I boot into Ubuntu. I can boot into recovery mode only. Shall I reconsider installing with MBR. Or is there any other workaround. I am very new to Ubuntu and I have no idea whats going around.

Comment: Do you have an Nvidia graphics card? If so, did you install the Nvidia drivers? Do you know how to boot with nomodeset?

Comment: Yes I'm having Nvidia Geforce GTX 1050Ti. I don't know what is nomodeset. I will check it out. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Let's find out what version Nvidia driver you have installed. `dpkg -l *nvidia* | grep ii`

Comment: Also show me `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version` and tell me the make/model of your computer. You'll probably have to do this and the prior command in Recovery Mode.

Comment: Were you able to find information about booting with nomodeset? Or shall I give you brief instructions?

Comment: See the accepted answer at https://askubuntu.com/questions/1085807/black-screen-after-installation-of-ubuntu-18-04 for how to use nomodeset.

Comment: Thank you everyone for taking your valuable time to answer my query. I just installed Nvidia drivers for my graphic card and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

From the comments...

Installed Nvidia driver 440.82 and it's all working now.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for putting in efforts to solve my query. In the meantime I upgraded to 20.04 and it works there as well.

Comment: Yeah I have done that, but since my reputation is less than 15, that won't affect the score. Sorry for that.

Comment: @Mandar Did you click the checkmark icon, or the up-arrow icon?